c programming: How does unions and structs with a tag and two names impact memory usage
EDIT..... I inherited this code. So please not rip it apart beyond the focus of the question.
I'm crunching some code for less ram usage on a small micro (Embedded system) and need some clarification on how does unions or structs impact memory if each has two names.
See the examples below.
union POR_Vectors 
{
    unsigned int Address;
    unsigned char Bytes[2];
}BL_POR_Vector, APP_POR_Vector;

and
struct FFC0_Flash 
{
    char BL_App_First_Run;          
    char APP_Says_Load_New_App;
}*Information, Ram_Information;

I would like to know if each example uses 2 or 4 memory locations for each union and struct?
My assumption is each name (variable) consumes two memory locations each.
But I want to make sure.

We’ll need to know the micro and compiler. But you can easily find out yourself by using sizeof.

@Gerald Eberhardt 2 or 4 or more? Avoid assumptions.  Please post your sizeof(unsigned) and sizeof(void*).

OT "... each name consumes ..." Using the term "name" here is a little odd. It would be more clear/common to call them variables. More strictly each "name" is an identifier for an object - often just called a "variable".

The code is fishy. We may note that professional programmers never use unsigned int etc in embedded systems, but instead use uint32_t etc from stdint.h. Especially they avoid char for expressing integers or raw data, since it's extra non-portable, given that it can be either signed or unsigned depending on compiler. Also these objects should likely have both const and volatile qualifiers. Overall it looks like code written by a PC programmer who got dropped on an embedded system.


My assumption is each name consumes two memory locations each.

Names do not consume any memory.

BL_POR_Vector, APP_POR_Vector you declare 2 objects of type union POR_Vectors, each will "consume" sizeof(union POR_Vectors) bytes of memory

2.*Information, Ram_Information; you define a pointer to struct FFC0_Flash and an object of type struct FFC0_Flash. The Pointer can only reference the object if it is initialized or assigned with a reference to the object or a memory location large enough to accommodate the object.

Information will have sizeof(struct FFC0_Flash *) size
Ram_Information will have sizeof(struct FFC0_Flash) size

Struct and unions may not have the size of their elements as the compiler is free to add padding.

Detail: "Pointer only can reference the object if inialized." --> Hope that includes assignment with Information = malloc(sizeof *Information);.

Also notice that sizeof unions and structs depends on the system (compiler) being used. In C sizeof(char) is always 1. However, a struct with two char type members could have a size being more than 2. It's unlikely but allowed. The only way to know is to check the compiler manual. As a test you can do: printf("struct FFC0_Flash size = %zu\n", sizeof(struct FFC0_Flash)); but that can change when changing compiler flags, e.g. optimization level.
